# Drupal8 , How Create Categories and Sub categories in Drupal 8 to separate blog by categories?

Tags: drupal, menu, categories, drupal-8

please help me to do following things on DRUPAL8, give me the idea on this.

How Create Categories and Sub categories in d8 to separate blog by categories

```
Ex: - 
            1   Game                                - Main categorie
                    Cricket                         - Sub category
                        Sachin         - blog Title
                        kohli          - blog Title
                    FootBall                            - Sub category
                        Messi          - blog Title
                        Ronaaldo       - blog Title

        2   Movie                               - Main categorie
                tamil                           - Sub category
                    kabali         - blog Title
                    Sivaji         - blog Title
                    duet           - blog Title
                English                         - Sub category
                    Wanted         - blog Title
                    Jurasic Park   - blog Title
                    Die Hard       - blog Title
                Telungu                         - Sub category
                    okadu          - blog Title
                    Bussiness Man   - blog Title**
```

---

```
 /**
 * @file
 */
(function () {

  "use strict";

  // All the JavaScript for this file.

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

For this my opinion is that the best way would be to go with Taxonomy.
You can create a Vocabulary for Game an one for Movie, adding all your subcategories as taxonomy terms.
There is no need for JavaScript.
If you supply more specifications i will be able to help you more.